# Issues with FindRoot. Getting error: FindRoot::eqlist: In the first argument {True,z1==0} only some of the components are equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a BVP for the system of equations. I need $r(0)$ and $\beta(0)$ to be fixed, and I need $r$ and $z$ to be fixed at the other end. I want $z(0)$ and the end value of $t$ to take any value necessary to have these conditions satisfied. I have been trying to use `FindRoot`, but it never works for me when I need it to find two variables instead of one. Am I using it wrong? Here's my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sol[(k_)?NumericQ, (z1_)?NumericQ, (tend_)?NumericQ] := {r[tend], z[tend]} /. 
  First[NDSolve[{(k + Derivative[1][β][t])*r[t] + Sin[β[t]] == 0, 
                 Derivative[1][r][t] == Cos[β[t]], 
                 Derivative[1][z][t] == Sin[β[t]], 
                 r[0] == 0.0001, z[0] == z1, β[0] == 0}, 
                 {r, z, β}, {t, 0, tend}]]
FindRoot[{sol[1, z1, tend][[1]] == 1, sol[1, z1, tend][[2]] == 0}, 
         {{tend, 1}, {z1, 1}}]
```

Also, if there is a better way to approach this problem, please let me know. Thank you!

EDIT 1: It works perfectly fine for one equation and one unknown:

```
sol1[(tend_)?NumericQ] := z[tend] /. 
  First[NDSolve[{(1.6 + Derivative[1][β][t])*r[t] + Sin[β[t]] == 0, 
                 Derivative[1][r][t] == Cos[β[t]], 
                 Derivative[1][z][t] == Sin[β[t]], 
                 r[0] == 0.0001, z[0] == 2, β[0] == 0}, 
                {r, z, β}, {t, 0, tend}]]
FindRoot[sol1[tend] == 0, {tend, 1}]
(* {tend -> 2.76777} *)
```

Comment: Of course if you plug in values in the definition, it will return True or False, however, what I have input there are equations indeed. They have variables in them that I ask FindRoot to solve for. Look at my EDIT 1. It works fine for one unknown. So the issue is not what you mention.

Comment: It could be an evaluation order issue. let me see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed by Nasser, it's a matter of evaluation order. Simplest solution is to add `Evaluated -> False`:

```
FindRoot[{sol[1, z1, tend][[1]] == 1, 
  sol[1, z1, tend][[2]] == 0}, {{tend, 1}, {z1, 1}}, Evaluated -> False]
```

Why does the original attempt fail? As we all know, though `FindRoot` owns the attribute `HoldAll`, it will try to *analyze* its arguments by default. During the analyzation, the arguments will be evaluated. `?NumericQ` will stop `FindRoot` from *touching* code inside `sol`, but it won't stop evaluation of expressions like `sol[1, z1, tend][[1]]`! What will happen then? We know `Part` (`[[]]`) works not only on `List` `{}`:

```
fff[aaa, bbb, c343434cc][[3]]
(* c343434cc *)

sol[1, z1, tend][[1]] 
(* 1 *)
sol[1, z1, tend][[2]] 
(* z1 *)
```

Then `sol[1, z1, tend][[1]] == 1` becomes `1 == 1` i.e. `True`, `sol[1, z1, tend][[2]] == 0` becomes `z1 == 0`.

So, another work-around is to use `Indexed` instead of `Part`, because `Indexed` extract elements only from `List`:

```
FindRoot[{Indexed[sol[1, z1, tend], 1] == 1, 
  Indexed[sol[1, z1, tend], 2] == 0}, {{tend, 1}, {z1, 1}}]
```

> … if there is a better way to approach this problem, please let me know.

Then you should not miss `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(k + β'[t]) r[t] + Sin[β[t]] == 0, 
    r'[t] == Cos[β[t]], z'[t] == Sin[β[t]], r[0] == 0.0001, 
    z[0] == z1, β[0] == 0}, {r[tend], z[tend]}, {t, 0, tend}, {k, z1, tend}];

FindRoot[psol[1, z1, tend] == {1, 0}, {{tend, 1}, {z1, 1}}]
(* {tend -> 1.0471, z1 -> 0.267949} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! This solved my issue.

Comment: @juv95 Forgot to mention `ParametricNDSolveValue` is a much better tool for attacking the problem. See my edit.