Why FindRoot gives wrong answer for the roots of a vector interpolation function
I've tried to use FindRoot to find the roots of a vector interpolation function,
but Mathematica is clearly giving me the wrong answer.
What's going on here?
Here is my code to reproduce the problem.
Thanks :)
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
dat = Table[{t, {2  Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.5}];
intp = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Hermite", 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3];
Plot[intp[t][[1]], {t, 0, 2}]
FindRoot[intp[t][[1]] == 0, {t, 0.5, 0, 2}]



Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273958/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282898/1871

Method-1

replace [[ ]],Part with Indexed.

FindRoot[Indexed[intp[t], 1] == 0, {t, 0.5, 0, 2}]


{t -> 1.57089}

Method-2

intp[t][[1]] return t,that is why the result not right. We can also use

F[t_?NumericQ] := intp[t][[1]];
FindRoot[F[t] == 0, {t, 0.5, 0, 2}]


{t -> 1.57089}

since for t belong to numeric number, intp[t][[1]] return the numeric first part of intp[t].
Method-3

Using Evaluated -> False to prevent intp[t][[1]] return t.

FindRoot[intp[t][[1]] == 0, {t, 0.5, 0, 2}, Evaluated -> False]


{t -> 1.57089}


Thank you very much for the explanation. Could you please explain a bit more about why my code using Part is incorrect?

You explained it so clearly！ Thanks, have a nicde day :)
